# I watched (a) hockey

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

A colleague told me today (none of us native English speakers):

> 1. I watched a hockey.

I told him that it is correct to say:

> 2. I watched hockey.

or:

> 3. I watched a hockey game.

However, I cannot answer the question: **why the first is incorrect**, the the others are correct? (Although I am not sure that 2. is correct either.)

My guess would be that "hockey" switches from noun to adjective, depending on the article. Also, it might be related to countability.

Comment: Like most names of sports, _hockey_ is a mass noun, and can never take the article _a_.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/articles/), **sports do not need articles.**

> I like to play baseball.

When you say, I watched **a** hockey game, then "a" refers to "game," not to "hockey."

So, it is correct to say:

> I watched hockey.

or

> I watched *a* hockey game.

When the listener/reader knows which exact game it is, you use the definite article "the:"

> I watched *the* hockey game.

---

A [general rule](https://www.englishpage.com/articles/advanced-articles.htm) is to use an article (a, the) before countable nouns, but there are *many* exceptions from this rule, for example, you usually don't use it before:

- sports (basketball, cricket)
- diseases (diabetes, Crohn's disease)
- countries (England, not *a* or *the* England)
- proper names (John, Mount Everest)

You omit "a" when you can't replace it with "one." You can't say one basketball or one England.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am especially interested in the "why", do you have some clarification about that?

Comment: @virolino There is no article before it (without different wording) because the names of sports (like many other things) are non-count nouns. It's not that you don't put articles in front of the names of sports per se, it's that you don't put articles in front of non-count nouns (unless they are mass nouns, which is not the case here).

Answer (score -1):

I believe the answer can be found here:

> https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252547/what-article-should-go-before-specific-games